# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: start near line 1, column 84

Tags: java, hibernate, connect-by

I am getting an error while executing the query. The error is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: start near line 1, column 84 [from com.services.om.entity.OrderLines where orderNumber in (:order_Numbers) start with parentLineIdentifier is null connect by prior orderLineIdentifier = parentLineIdentifier]

My DAO code is :

```
public List<OrderLineVO> findAllOrders(List<BigDecimal>  orderNumbers) throws OrderManagementException {
        try{

            String getAllOrders = "from OrderLines where orderNumber in (:order_Numbers) order by orderDate desc ";

            Query query = em.createQuery(getAllOrders,OrderLines.class);
            query.setParameter("order_Numbers", orderNumbers);
            List<OrderLines>  orderLinesList = query.getResultList();


            String queryParentChild = "from OrderLines where orderNumber in (:order_Numbers) start with parentLineIdentifier is null connect by prior orderLineIdentifier = parentLineIdentifier";
                        Query queryParent = em.createQuery(queryParentChild, OrderLines.class);
            queryParent.setParameter("order_Numbers", orderNumbers);

            List<OrderLines>  orderLinesList2 = queryParent.getResultList();

            return OrderLineUTIL.getOrderLines(orderLinesList);
        }catch(Exception exception){
            logger.error(exception.getMessage());
            throw new OrderManagementException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

em.createQuery(queryParentChild, OrderLines.class); // Line is giving above error.
```

Any Suggestion ?

Also the entity class field variables are marked correctly in query.